# How to execute a script when a Linux machine starts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and I want to execute the following 3 statements when it starts:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Xms32m -Xmx64m'

cd ~

appengine-java-sdk-1.6.4/bin/dev_appserver.sh --port=8080 appengine-java-sdk-1.6.4/demos/VosaoCMS/war
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

1. Place your commands in a file and place the file in the `/etc/init.d/` directory. For example, `appengine-startup-script`
2. Make the script file executable. (E.g. `chmod +x appengine-startup-script`)
3. Run `update-rc.d [filename] defaults` (E.g. `update-rc.d appengine-startup-script defaults`
4. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You can also put an entry in your /etc/crontab whose runtime is set to `@reboot`. This will only fire the script off when your machine reboots.

Something like this:

`@reboot /opt/Adrian/script.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty way would be to save those commands to a script (don't forget the shebang), make it executable, and then call the script on boot by placing the full path on a blank line at the end of `/etc/rc.local`.

This can get messy if you do it for a lot of different startup jobs, but for simple tasks `rc.local` is probably the quickest/easiest way to spawn a process on startup.